# Merging layers with same name in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

Is there a way to merge all the layers with same name using python script in QGIS in the following list;

```
names = [layer.name() for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()]
print names
```

Output:

```
[u'Pois', u'Pois', u'Pois', u'Pois', u'Pois', u'Pois', u'Pois', u'Pois', u'Pois']
```

So that when I list my current mapLayers, all I get is one layer with all the other layers merged into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use processing algorithms :

```
import processing
processing.alghelp("qgis:mergevectorlayers")

pois_lyr_list = []
lyr_list = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()
for layer in lyr_list:
    if layer.name() == u'Pois':
         pois_lyr_list.append(layer)

processing.runandload("qgis:mergevectorlayers", pois_lyr_list, "memory:merged")
```

Comment: I think @raosaeedali wants to merge layers which have the same name :)

Comment: @Joseph exactly.

Comment: @joseph, Ok I added a loop to add in list only layers with name == u'Pois'

Comment: Getting the following error;
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: Figured it out. It was because in lyr_list u'Pois20180207171404510 was shown instead of u'Pois'.

Comment: Still its not merging all features from the layers.

Comment: Can you be more precise?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version for QGIS3. Note that I hardcoded CRS and result directory.

To get help for other CRS options you can run in Python Console:

```py
import processing
processing.algorithmHelp('native:mergevectorlayers')
```

Merge layers with same name script:

```py
import processing

grouped_layers_by_name = {}
distinct_layer_names = set()

project_layers = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().children()

for layer_item in project_layers:
    layer_name = layer_item.name()
    distinct_layer_names.add(layer_name)
    grouped_layers_by_name[layer_name] = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name);

print('Total number of distinct layers: ' + str(len(distinct_layer_names)))

for layer_name in distinct_layer_names:
    print('Processing layer: ' + layer_name + '... ', end='')
    merged_layer_file_name = 'D:/merged/' + layer_name + '.gpkg'
    alg_params = {
        'LAYERS': grouped_layers_by_name[layer_name],
        'CRS': 'EPSG:3765',
        'OUTPUT': merged_layer_file_name
    }

    result = processing.run('native:mergevectorlayers', alg_params)
    print('done.')

print('All layers have been merged.')
```

Comment: Can this be use without, because I am looking for something similar but I have tables without geometry and I want to export it as csv/xls.

Answer (score 0):

Simple version updated for QGIS3

```
import processing

listLayers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Points')

processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers", 
                             {'LAYERS':listLayers,
                             'CRS':3006,
                             'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```